# Call MATLAB method compiled to .NET assembly from C#

Tags: c#, matlab, matlab-deployment

I've created a script file in MATLAB R2010a with the following code. I compiled it into a .NET assembly (.dll file).

MATLAB script:

```
function res=Moshtagh(f)
    res=diff(f);
end
```

This works ok in MATLAB.
Note that in my dll the class name is `Difer` and my method to calculate the derivative is `Moshtagh`.

C# Code :

```
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.ComponentData;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;
try
{
    Untitled3.Difer dif = new Untitled3.Difer();
    MWArray mw = "x+sin(2*x)";
    MessageBox.Show(dif.Moshtagh(mw).ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

But the problem is instead of getting the result `1+2cos(2x)`, the message box shows:

```
-77 72 -10 5 -70 10 -8 78 -79
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you should define `mw` as `MWCharArray`, not as `MWArray`.

```
  Untitled3.Difer dif = new Untitled3.Difer();
  MWCharArray mw = new MWCharArray("x+sin(2*x)");
  MessageBox.Show(dif.Moshtagh(mw).ToString());
```

Another guess is that `Moshtagh` expects first argument as `int` -  `nargout=1`

```
  MWArray out = dif.Moshtagh(1,mw);
```

Comment: i tested it,but nothing affected !

Comment: @salar, As far as I remember, the first argument of a compiled .NET function is always nargout - it is an int. So you should put there "1"